# How to select 2nd column value on the basis of 1st column vale in select statement in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

As show in screenshot, i have one table corporate_calender containing all the working day (if holiday =0)and holiday (if holiday =1).
I want to select each working day date and last working day date 
i.e i want to use output of 1st column in 2nd column
i tried below query, but it is giving error.
"Invalid column name 'workingday'."

```
Select Date workingday,
       (select Max(Date)  
        from Corporate_Calendar 
        where holiday =0 
          and date>workingday)lastworkingday 
from Corporate_Calendar 
where holiday =0
```

[image]

Comment: What error is it giving?

Comment: have you tried using self join? Use different alias for table and use it for filtering second column  data based on first column values.. Assign square bracket date

Comment: i have used workingday as alias name for the 1st column,it is not the column name of the corporate_calender table

Comment: @yog2411  Please assist me with self join

Comment: @LaxminarayanCharan please refer this link http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/what-is-a-self-join/. also did you try wrapping up the date column in bracket? since its reserved keyword as explained in the first comment

Comment: I am not fully positive what you are wanting but it sounds like you want to find the first and last working day after each holiday occurs?  There are several methods of doing this.  But please update your question with an esample your expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is you create one alias and try to use on the inside query, and you cant do that

Also some fixs

- Date is a reserverd word, so should be include it with `[Date]` or better yet use a different name
- use alias to use the same table outiside and inside

  - CC1 and CC2

.

```
Select cc1.[Date] workingday,
      ( select Max(cc2.[Date])  
        from Corporate_Calendar  cc2
        where cc2.[holiday] = 0 
          and cc2.[date] > cc1.[Date]
                                ^^^^ cant use the alias
      ) as lastworkingday 
from Corporate_Calendar cc1
where cc1.[holiday] = 0
```

if you want use the alias you need wrap it as a sub query.

```
 SELECT *
 FROM (SELECT cc1.[Date] as workingDay
       FROM Corporate_Calendar as cc1
      ) T
 WHERE T.workingDay > 0
```